# Связки между элементами в двунаправленном списке

Tags: структуры

Использование различного вида связки для работы с двунаправленными списками.
Кто что может сказать по этому поводу?
В гугле про "двунаправленные" информации хватает, а вот насчет "различных видов связки" этих списков я ничего не нашёл...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроме **классических двунаправленных** списков с двумя указателями на элемент, существуют также так называемые [**Skip lists,**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) которые ускоряют поиск в списке до `log(n)` засчет большего количества требуемой памяти.

Соответственно, несложно представить себе двунаправленную вариацию `skip list`, которая и будет являться *"другим видом связи"*.

Answer (score 0):

А какие вы предполагаете виды связей? Слева - Справа, других вроде как нема

Можно так ( html node ) : Родитель-Первый ребёнок-Право, но это уже не двунаправленный